# How to send basic geo data in the measurement protocol api?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm sending ecommerce data using the google analytics 4 measurement protocol and I also load the basic ga4 js snippet to track geo and other flow data.

The only issue is, as expected, I don't get any geo location data when the user is ad blocking and the ga4 js doesn't load.

Is there a way to send basic geo location data using the measurement protocol api so the realtime map works even when js is being blocked?

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop your own server-side service using the GA4 Measurement protocol, and make a fetch() yourself in javascript to that web-service:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4

But some `user_properties` parameters, like geolocation, are not documented (or do not exist) yet.

See question here: [How indentity user country through GA4 measurement protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70666130/how-indentity-user-country-through-ga4-measurement-protocol)