# How indentity user country through GA4 measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

It is possible retrieve geo location through GA4 Measurement protocol? How i must configure  json body to send geo location (for example via HitBuilder)?

Comment: The measurement protocol is used to send data TO google analytics you cant retrieve anything from it so there for the Anwser is no.

Comment: I mean to send message to GA4 that to know where is the user from (Country). In Universal GA this is done with event "geoid".

Answer (score 6):

I have same issue and asked Google in below ticket:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237566549

So the Answer is they are not supported yet.